# vectorization of loops by compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, vectorization, compiler-optimization

I have a very basic question concerning optimization done by the compiler (in my case gcc) using -O flag. I would like to focus here only on vectorization of loops. Assume a simple for-loop without the danger of pointer aliasing/ race conditions. Is it possible to rewrite this loop in a way which makes the code generated by the compiler with -O0 flag as fast as it would be if the loop was vectorized by the compiler?

Comment: I have no idea why this was voted to close as "too broad".

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care about the efficiency of -O0 code? If you want the code to be fast, why compile with -O0?

Comment: -O0 specifically turns off optimization, so no optimization is done when you pass -O0.

Comment: @JoshHaberman: I know  that -O0 turns off optimization. I simply wonder if it is possible to have more control over the optimization process by applying "vectorization by hand", directly in the c++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely: nope. Using -O0 gives the compiler carte blanche to make the code as inefficient as it wants to. Ofcourse, it is not some evil beasty that wants to mess with you, but it won't try hard unless you tell it to either.

Some optimizations must generally be done by the compiler. You cannot, in general, get the same performance through micro-optimizations in your source code as you could get using aggressive compiler optimizations.

Regarding your specific example: yes, you can include vector directives in your code to enforce the use of vector instructions. Your code probably won't work on all platforms if you do such things, though, unless you know *very* well what you're doing and always provide fallbacks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So this vector directives are given by the processor architecture, right? Can you give an example?

Comment: These directives are generally compiler and instruction set specific. You can find an example here http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-38C9CE7E-26DF-4F81-A0AC-B4CEDF284781.htm

Comment: perfect, this is what I was searching for!